# Mips double division returns Infinity

Tags: assembly, double, mips, division, mars-simulator

I've condensed my problem to the following code:

```
.data

newline: .asciiz "\n"

.text
.globl main

main:

li $t0, 4
li $t1, 16          

mtc1 $t0, $f2       # Two integers get stored as floats
mtc1 $t1, $f30

div.d $f12, $f2, $f30

li $v0, 3
syscall         # First division works, returns 0.25

la $a0, newline
li $v0, 4
syscall         # prints new line

div.d $f12, $f12, $f30

li $v0, 3
syscall         # Second division doesn't work as expected, returns Infinity
```

Output is:

```
0.25

Infinity
```

Why is that? I'd expect `0.25/16` to be ~ `0.015625` instead of `Infinity`.

First value of $f12: 0x3fd0000000000000
Second value of $f12:0x7ff0000000000000

I'm relatively new to MIPS so it might be something easy.
Thanks for any answers!

Comment: It looks like you have a typo in the second division: div.d $f12, $f12, $f30. You never show $f12 to be initialized, I suspect it contains zero.

Comment: Shouldn't it contain something after 'div.d $f12, $f2, $f30' ? Or does it get overwritten when calling to print it?

Comment: The `MTC1` instruction does not convert an integer into a double. You need to use `CVT.D.W` after the move.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked! But why does the first division work and why does the second division return Infinity?

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with the MIPS ABI, but perhaps certain registers are being clobbered by the `syscall`s, and no longer contain the values you think they should...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The apparent success of the first division is due to an artifact of how small positive integers and positive subnormal doubles are represented. Both have leading zeros, with the binary bit pattern corresponding to the significant bits of the value in the least significant bits. The effect of treating the integers as doubles was to divide each value by 2 to the power 1074.

Although f2 and f30, viewed as double precision float, contained tiny values, about 2.0E-323 and 7.9E-323, their ratio was the same as 4/16. Dividing a moderate number such as 0.25 by a tiny number overflows to infinity.

Here is a short Java program illustrating this:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long t0 = 4;
    long t1 = 16;
    double f2 = Double.longBitsToDouble(t0);
    double f30 = Double.longBitsToDouble(t1);
    System.out.println("f2=" + f2);
    System.out.println("f30=" + f30);
    double f12 = f2 / f30;
    System.out.println("f12=" + f12);
    System.out.println("f12/f30=" + f12 / f30);
  }
}
```

output:

```
f2=2.0E-323
f30=7.9E-323
f12=0.25
f12/f30=Infinity
```

Comment: That's a great answer! And it's a great example of how multiple bugs can cancel each other out.